# how to subtract a part of a string into a new variable in my dataframe?

Tags: r, regex, string, split, gsub

i need i way to subtract a part of a string from one variable to create a new variable

i have e.g.

```r
df <- c(" 3 Rue d Argentine 16th arr 75116 Paris France", 
"5 Passage Ruelle 18th arr 75018 Paris France", " 1 Avenue Carnot 17th arr 75017 Paris France", "Bis Rue De Vaugirard 6th arr 75006 Paris France", "6 Impasse Marteau 18th arr 75018 Paris France" ," 1 Place De La Sorbonne 5th arr 75005 Paris France", "1 Place Vend me 1st arr 75001 Paris France")
```

what i want to have is a new variable that subtract the arrondissements so my new dataframe becomes

```
adress: " 3 Rue d Argentine 16th arr 75116 Paris France", 
"5 Passage Ruelle 18th arr 75018 Paris France", " 1 Avenue Carnot 17th arr 75017 Paris France", "Bis Rue De Vaugirard 6th arr 75006 Paris France", "6 Impasse Marteau 2nd arr 75018 Paris France" ," 1 Place De La Sorbonne 5th arr 75005 Paris France", "1 Place Vend me 1st arr 75001 Paris France"

arr: "16th", "18th", "17th", "6th", "2nd", "5th", "1st"
```

etc.
can anybody help me on how to do this in R ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, while I don't doubt that there are applicable dupes for this, *that* dupe is about removing the `st|nd|rd|th` ordinal from a pattern, not for extracting the whole number+ordinal. While you or I could likely adapt those removal regexes to preserve it as well ... I don't get the idea that this OP knows enough regex to be able to adapt that.

Answer (score 0):

A base R method could be:

```r
unlist(regmatches(df, gregexpr("\\b(\\S+)(?=\\sarr)", df, perl=TRUE)))
# [1] "16th" "18th" "17th" "6th"  "18th" "5th"  "1st"
```

Using `gsub` might be a mistake here, because if `arr` is not found then it will return the whole string.

If you'd rather use `stringr`, then

```r
stringr::str_extract(df, "\\b(\\S+)(?=\\sarr)")
# [1] "16th" "18th" "17th" "6th"  "18th" "5th"  "1st"
```

Both regexes utilize "lookahead". The pattern broken down:

- `\\b` word boundary; this does not include any characters, it ensures that the pattern to its left and/or right have some blank-space here
- `(\\S+)` one or more (`+`) non-blank-space characters (`\\S`)
- `(?=\\sarr)` is a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that ensures the enclosed text (`\\s` is a blank-space, and the literal `arr`) is found after the desired pattern, *but it is not "consumed"*; using this requires `perl=TRUE`

With the base R version, `gregexpr` returns a list of indices where the pattern is found within each element of the input (`df`), and can be used for extraction (as in here) or even replacement (`` `regmatches<-` ``).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work using positive lookahead:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(arr = str_extract(address, '\\d+..(?=\\sarr)'))
                                             address  arr
1      3 Rue d Argentine 16th arr 75116 Paris France 16th
2       5 Passage Ruelle 18th arr 75018 Paris France 18th
3        1 Avenue Carnot 17th arr 75017 Paris France 17th
4    Bis Rue De Vaugirard 6th arr 75006 Paris France  6th
5      6 Impasse Marteau 18th arr 75018 Paris France 18th
6  1 Place De La Sorbonne 5th arr 75005 Paris France  5th
7         1 Place Vend me 1st arr 75001 Paris France  1st
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good option:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df,"[0-9]+(th|nd|st)")

# [1] "16th" "18th" "17th" "6th"  "18th" "5th"  "1st"
```